# In ConTeXt, make new float with padding NOT stick out of the textwidth

Tags: floats, context

I want to define a new float to enclose my document examples in a frame with grey bakcground.
Here is my preamble code so far:

```
\setupcolumns[n=2]

\definefloat[example][examples]
\definemeasure[atdmexampleoffset][10pt]
\definemeasure[atdmexamplewidth][\dimexpr\textwidth-2\measure{atdmexampleoffset}]
\setupfloat[example][
    location=middle,
    frame=on,
    width=\measure{atdmexamplewidth}, % <------
    offset=\measure{atdmexampleoffset},
    background=color,
    backgroundcolor=atdm-lightgrey%
]
```

I use the float with this code:

```
\starttext
\startcolumns

\placeexample[here][ex:foo]{Foo}{%
    For instance: foo. Or bar. Or both. etc.
}

\stopcolumns
\stoptext
```

The issue I have is that the example text spans over exactly \textwidth, thus making the frame stick out of `2*offset` on the right of standard text body (see the gap between the red and green rules).

[image]

The width parameter unfortunately seems to have no effect.

Note that the same issue arise with single-column text, only the float stays centered and sticks out by `offset` both on the left and the right.

How could I make the float occupy the same width as the text below and above it?

Comment: It is perhaps better if you give a complete but minimal (non)working example. That way, the people who will help you need not to work so much.

Comment: Post edited. Concatenating the two code snippets now gives a mwe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should put your texts in a `framedtext` environment where you can the offset for the margins.

```
\starttext

\startcolumns

\input knuth

\startplacefloat[title=Zapf]
    \startframedtext[width=max,background=color,backgroundcolor=gray]
    \input zapf
    \stopframedtext
\stopplacefloat

\input tufte

\startplacefloat[title=Ward]
    \startframedtext[width=max,background=color,backgroundcolor=gray]
    \input ward
    \stopframedtext
\stopplacefloat

\input weisman

\stopcolumns

\stoptext
```

[image]